# How to maintain state of a control inside a gridview which has paging enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, state-management

I have a gridview of 4 columns including a column as Approve. Approve is having a checkbox which will repeat for all the rows of the dataset after binding. I have made allowpaging = true & pageindexsize to be 10. Now, suppose i check checkbox of row 2 and 5, and move to page 2, and come back to page 1, the checkboxes that i checked(of row 2 and 5) on page 1 is getting reset to unchecked state. I know the reason, that it is due to the binding of the gridview that we do on onpageindexchanging event. But is there any way to maintain the state of  checkbox even if we move from 1 page to another.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session to maintain the values. One Page index change event you need to add values to session and rebind the checkboxes.

Here is few links which may help you

1. http://forums.asp.net/p/1368550/2852029.aspx
2. http://myaspsnippets.blogspot.com/2010/08/maintaining-state-of-checkboxes-while.html

Comment: what should i store in session? the row index of the gridview of which the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Try the second link I provided, it has got a sample code, which may help you.

Comment: Thanks. The second links gives my answer, anybody in search can look on the same. Took time as i didnt get time to get back here and mark it as answer, sry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try,  (You'll have to set the two events Checkbox_Checked and Checkbox_PreRender to the CheckBox control in the grid.  Also the DataKey will have to be set in the grid so that there will be an index into the Checks array.)

```
protected bool[] Checks
{
    get { return (bool[])(ViewState["Checks"] ?? new bool[totalLengthOfDataSource]); }
    set { ViewState["Checks"] = value; }
}

protected void Checkbox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool[] checks = Checks;
    checks[(int)GetRowDataKeyValue(sender)] = cb.Checked;
    Checks = checks;
}

protected void Checkbox_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool[] checks = Checks;
    cb.Checked = checks[(int)GetRowDataKeyValue(sender)];
}
```

These work best in a static GridViewUtils class.

```
public static GridViewRow GetRow(object sender)
{
    Control c = (Control)sender;
    while ((null != c) && !(c is GridViewRow))
        c = c.NamingContainer;
    return (GridViewRow)c;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the Grid the row is in
/// </summary>
/// <param name="row"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static GridView GetGrid(this GridViewRow row)
{
    Control c = (Control)row;
    while ((null != c) && !(c is GridView))
        c = c.NamingContainer;
    return (GridView)c;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the ID field value based on DataKey and row's index
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">Any web-control object in the grid view</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static object GetRowDataKeyValue(object sender)
{
    try
    {
        GridViewRow row = GetRow(sender);
        GridView grid = row.GetGrid();
        return grid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

> Create a bool property on your bindable object called "userSelected" (or similar)
>   Create an indexer by object ID on your bindable list object
>   On grid_RowDataBound add your bindable object's ID as an attribute to the checkbox
>   On grid_RowDataBound also set your checkbox's checked property to obj.userSelected
>   On chech_CheckChaged use your indexer to set your bindable object's userSelected property

Thanks

Comment: Please format your answers, use enters and ``` sign to emphasize e.g. property names

Answer (score 0):

I tried the PreRender techniques from @Chuck, but it didn't work for me (VS2005, ASP.net2, SQLsrv2005). Maybe too old technology, but it's what the client has.

So I tried the simple [myaspsnippets](http://myaspsnippets.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/maintaining-state-of-checkboxes-while.html) technique, and with some modifications it works perfectly!

My Gridview

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gvFTUNSENT" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" AllowSorting="False" CssClass="gvCSS" Width="100%"
                    DataKeyNames="StudentID,StudentUnitID" DataSourceID="sdsFTUNSENT" 
                    GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                    OnPageIndexChanged="GridView_PageIndexChanged" 
                    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging">
                    <RowStyle Wrap="True" Height="48px" />
                    <Columns>
...etc...
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="100%" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" BackColor="#6B696B" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" Height="100%" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

The Pageing methods I used are:

```
protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;

    //saves a "copy" of the page before it's changed over to the next one
    SavePageState(gv);

    gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

and

```
    protected void GridView_PageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
...your code to handle anything after the page has changed

                    gv.DataSource = dt;
                    gv.DataSourceID = null;
                    gv.DataBind();

                    //reload any checkboxes that were session saved in the page
                    LoadPageState(gv);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So the SAVE and LOAD methods are as follows:

```
private void SavePageState(GridView gv)
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
    Int32 index = -1;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
        HiddenField hfStudentUnitID = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfStudentUnitID");
        if (hfStudentUnitID != null)
        {
            if (hfStudentUnitID.Value.Length > 0)
            {
                index = Convert.ToInt32(hfStudentUnitID.Value.ToString()); //gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["StudentUnitID"];
                bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbSEND")).Checked;

                // Check in the Session
                if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
                    categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
                if (result)
                {
                    if (!categoryIDList.Contains(index))
                        categoryIDList.Add(index);
                }
                else
                    categoryIDList.Remove(index);
            }
        }
    }
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
        Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = categoryIDList;
}
```

AND

```
private void LoadPageState(GridView gv)
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            HiddenField hfStudentUnitID = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfStudentUnitID");
            if (hfStudentUnitID != null)
            {
                if (hfStudentUnitID.Value.Length > 0)
                {
                    Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(hfStudentUnitID.Value.ToString()); //gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["StudentUnitID"];
                    if (categoryIDList.Contains(index))
                    {
                        CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cbSEND");
                        myCheckBox.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To make this work for you, you'll need to place the Paging method calls into your GridView, change the CheckBox ID from cbSEND to what ever you're using, and point the HiddenFields to some other control or value that has a unique identifier for your rows. **Don't** use `RowIndex`, as that is not unique throughout the length of the data in your GridView.

Works like a charm!